# Which pathway is better for robinson cycloaddition? 2-phenylacetaldehyde + 3-buten-2-one or 2-phenyl-2-propenal + acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

So this was a question on my orgII exam yesterday. The target molecule is 4-phenyl-2-cyclohexenone. By retrosynthetic analysis there is only one possible aldol condensation reaction, but two possible michael addition reactions afterwards. My "guess" was that the best one is 2-phenyl-2-propenal + acetone because in the other case the negative charge is delocalized throughout the benzene ring reducing the nucleophilic character of the a-carbon and also activating the ring in which case EAS could take place with the ring acting as the "Michael Donor".

Comment: The phenylacetaldehyde route is better because of the easy availability of the starting materials

Comment: Either route is subject to the difficulty that the double bond will isomerise into conjugation with phenyl ring giving 4-phenylcyclohex-3-enone

Comment: @Waylander I went and asked my teacher and it turns out the same exact exercise was solved in the textbook. The answer was what I said, but for very different reasons. Aldehydes undergo aldol condensation in base much faster than simple ketones. So, the issue with using the 2 - phenylacetaldehyde is aldol condensation with another same molecule as a side reaction.

Comment: This is where I take issue with your teacher. In the real world you would do the phenylacetaldehyde route (modified to reduce self-condensation) because of the easy availablility of the starting materials. 2-Phenyl-2-propenal is not widely available (ask your teacher how they would make it), you would have to make it first which means running and working up  two reactions rather than one.

Comment: To be honest I totally agree with you. I thought that using an excess of the ketone would probably greatly slow down the self-condensation process among other various procedures with the same goal. However, when she pointed that the exercise was identical to the one in the textbook I didn't continue the debate. Perhaps it's her mistake or perhaps she wanted an "easy" and already solved exercise to aid those who didn't study much. To my knowledge, there wasn't any other imprecise problem in the rest of test.

Comment: In my experience textbook answers rarely mirror the actual practice of chemistry. They are there to illustrate a principle.